# Putting spaces in file directory string

Tags: c, file-io

I am new to file I/O, and I am writing a program in C to read a file that I already created. The examples in the book I have do not use literals with spaces. I was wondering if:

```
#define kErrorLog      "/Dropbox/Dev/Learn%20C%20on%20Mac/Error%20Log"
```

would give me the appropriate path that corresponds to `user/dropbox/dev/Learn C on Mac/Error Log`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; the file name need not be URL-encoded like that. You can include spaces normally:

```
#define kErrorLog      "/Dropbox/Dev/Learn C on Mac/Error Log"
```

In general, there is no need to escape file names in C. If you're putting a file name directly in your code, you might need to escape problematic characters inside a string literal (for example, backslashes), but once you have it in a string, no modifications need to be made to that string to use it as a file name.

Answer (score 2):

No, you should just use spaces:

```
#define kErrorLog      "/Dropbox/Dev/Learn C on Mac/Error Log"
```

The `%20` escape is interpreted by web servers. Filenames are just character strings.